# Is it possible to make a crytographically strong/safe salt with PHP's built in functions and no mcrypt?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, crypt, initialization-vector

I need to generate a salt (to pass to crypt) but the server doesn't have mcrypt (and I do not have the ability to put it there). Is there a way I can do it with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or another built-in PHP function?

**It is important that it has safe-randomness.**

My mcrypt was:

```
$salt = "$" . $algorithm . "$" . $length . "$";
$salt .= substr( str_replace( "+", ".", base64_encode( mcrypt_create_iv( 128, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM ) ) ), 0, 22 );
return $salt;
```

How would I do this without mcrypt?

Comment: How would I use the option suggested there with `crypt`? I can't get it to work.

Comment: If you look at the top rated answer in that situation and you are not using this for commercial use, then you can generate a random value using `mt_rand()` and then running `uniqid()` on the previous value.

Comment: @BrandonWhite I ended up with a much more secure option: `$salt = "$2a$12$" . bin2hex( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( 22, $strongCheck ) );`